# Start mongos with chef

Tags: ruby, mongodb, chef-infra

I'm trying to launch mongos using chef by calling `/etc/init.d/mongos start`.

my recipe:

```
# service.rb

service 'mongos' do
  supports(start: true, stop: true, status: true, restart: true,
           reload: true, condrestart: true, :'force-reload' => true)
  action :nothing
end
```

and

```
# default.rb

include_recipe 'mongos::service'
service 'mongos' do
  action :start
end
```

But it fails when I run the recipe, because he doesn't run the command with `sudo`.

How can i make chef run the service command with sudo?

thanks.

Comment: Chef should be running as root and thus not need sudo... I doubt the problem is that it is lacking sudo...

Comment: I'm using opsworks, do you know how to tell opsworks to run the recipes with sudo?

Comment: Unfortunately I have never used AWS opsworks and thus do not know.  However, as I said before, chef SHOULD run as the root user otherwise you are going to run into a slew of problems.  If it is not running as the root user then there is something strange going on

Comment: Can you post the error output from the chef run?

Comment: Error output:
https://gist.github.com/letz/32b7fc4b4c42ef8ef3c7

Comment: That could be caused by so many different reasons. Have you confirmed that `/etc/init.d/mongos` actually exists and you can start it as the root user using `/etc/init.d/mongos start`? Running as the root user should not require sudo

Comment: yes, the file exists, and I can start as root user

Comment: huh that is mysterious. Will an execute resource with the same command I listed above fail on a chef convergence?